# Error when setting new routes in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have an URL: mydomain.com/view/page/about
then i want change it to be: mydomain.com/page/about

i’ve tried add a new routes:
$route[‘page/(:any)’] = ‘view/page/$1’;

but when i refresh my browser, it always show the page in: mydomain.com/view/page/index
any advice to solve my problem?

thank you before

Answer (score 0):

Note that `mydomain.com/page` won't get you to `view/page`. Your regexp expects there to be a ending `/` in the url.

Either do a

```
$route[‘page/?(:any)’] = ‘view/page/$1’;
```

Or

```
$route[‘page’] = ‘view/page’;
$route[‘page/(:any)’] = ‘view/page/$1’;
```

If you wish to be more accurate.